# how to keep same positions of <h2> topics in 3 columns?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML codes to maintain the same width 3 columns.
css file is

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: auto;
  height: 800px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

html file is,

```
<h2>Three Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

now I need keep all column  tag data in same potisions. how could I do this using my css file?
**edit**
screen shot
[![some screen shot
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIcnK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIcnK.png)

Comment: IDK I did not understand what you want to do exactly!

Comment: okay simply this is I need keep all <h2> tag data in same positions in the columns. as an example  if more content include in <p> tag then other columns <h2> tag data position may change (not in same line to other column position )

Comment: Can you make and example for me and screenshot it? I did not understand clearly!

Comment: I have added some screenshot now you can see

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you want the column items to be next to each other instead of in the same horizontal line, why do you use "row" divs? The example in the screenshot is using just 3 column divs.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: auto;
  height: 800px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>Three Equal Columns</h2>


  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>

    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text.. </p>

   <h2>Title longer</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus feugiat porta. Curabitur dui est, bibendum in nisl quis, tempor dictum nisi. Nam vel aliquam ligula. In eget nunc odio. Aenean ornare elit sed augue sodales consectetur. Nam sagittis leo nunc, sit amet consectetur lorem dignissim sed. Praesent hendrerit massa orci, et gravida mauris porta vel. Morbi eget efficitur augue. Nullam id magna id magna finibus blandit sit amet eu tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas tincidunt enim id finibus pretium. In varius elit hendrerit, tempor magna in, vehicula turpis.</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text.. </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus feugiat porta.</p>
     <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
        <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
        <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
        <h2>Title Medium</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus feugiat porta. Curabitur dui est, bibendum in nisl quis, tempor dictum nisi. Nam vel aliquam ligula. In eget nunc odio. Aenean ornare elit sed augue sodales consectetur. Nam sagittis leo nunc, sit amet consectetur lorem dignissim sed. Praesent hendrerit massa orci, et gravida mauris porta vel. Morbi eget efficitur augue. Nullam id magna id magna finibus blandit sit amet eu tortor. </p>
  
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
        <h2>Title Short</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus feugiat porta. Curabitur dui est, bibendum in nisl quis, tempor dictum nisi. Nam vel aliquam ligula. In eget nunc odio. Aenean ornare elit sed augue sodales consectetur. Nam sagittis leo nunc, sit amet consectetur lorem dignissim sed. Praesent hendrerit massa orci, et gravida mauris porta vel. Morbi eget efficitur augue. Nullam id magna id magna finibus blandit sit amet eu tortor. </p>
        <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
        <h2>Title Shorter</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dapibus feugiat porta. Curabitur dui est, bibendum in nisl quis, tempor dictum nisi. Nam vel aliquam ligula. In eget nunc odio. Aenean ornare elit sed augue sodales consectetur.</p>
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
```